# How does "see votes" privilege work?

Tags: support, privileges

Recently I earned the "see votes" privilege. What does it do and how to use it?

Answer (score 4):

If you click on the number of votes on the left side of a post, it will expand to show you the number of upvotes and downvotes rather than just the end total. [More details on the "established user" privileges.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user)

[image: Click to see vote totals]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on mobile devices

Comment: @FrancisL. [Looks like you have to use the desktop site or the app](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/292208/3511560)

Comment: @FrancisL. I just tested and it works on both the mobile website and the app, however there is a difference. The mobile website seems to work best with a quick tap, where as I find I need to press and hold a moment in the app.